# Rails - How do I adjust a parent attribute, based on a child attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Ok, I am looking to implement something fairly straight forward in a Rails app I would say, but rails callbacks, transactions and caches are getting the better of me.

**This is what I want to achieve:**
Two objects `project` and `task`. Both have an attribute `finish_date`. Also a `project :has_many => :tasks`.

I want to tell the `project` that its own `finish_date` can never be earlier than the latest `finish_date` on its `tasks`. Whenever a `task` is updated, the `project` parent should check and adjust its own `finish_date` if required.

I have been messing with `after_save` callbacks and its not as simple as I imagined due to transactions and multiple versions of the same object in memory. Perhaps I am just doing it wrong.

**How could I implement this in Rails?**

Comment: what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: no errors. the project finish_date is not updated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following `Task` model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  def after_save(task)
    self.project.finish_date = self.finish_date
  end
end
```

The project's `finish_date` will be set to the task's `finish_date`. The code is assuming, the currently saved tasked always has a later `finished_date` as any other. It that's a wrong assumption, just add the appropriate `if` statement :)

**EDIT**

My suggestion from the comment would be to have the `Task` as listed above and overwrite the `finish_date` setter in `Project` like so:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks

  def finished_date=(new_finish_date)
    self[:finish_date] = new_finish_date if self[:finish_date] < new_finish_date
  end
end
```

Since I'm coding from my head, I'm not sure whether the project instance should be saved after this. Perhaps using `update_attributes` in the setter might be a better idea.

**About the other solutions here**

@Joelios solution suggested what I did, only not with overriding the setter. The problem with that is, that Rails included methods always use the setter (even `update_attributes` and `create`). So with that, you had to call method `update_task_date` on your own which one might forget.

@saverios solution suggests to use the Observer/Observable pattern. So, as I see it, `Project` would become an observer of all its `Task` objects. When a `Task` changes, it calls all its observers, i.e. its project, which itself updates its `finish_date`. It's more of less the same what I suggested just with using a design pattern, hence making it more difficult.

Another solution one could think about is to define a new function like `update` in `Project` which iterates through all connected tasks, looking for the newest `finish_date`. That `update` method would have to be called whenever a task updates. That would be really bad design because each update of one of n tasks would trigger n database queries and slow everything down.

Hope that helps someone facing the same problem.

Comment: this would probably work, but if I implement like this suddenly my task model has logic in it that changes the project object. I don't really like that. Makes it messy imo. Thanks for reply though!

Comment: Well, if you don't allow change from outside the model, you can neither update nor create it, because you set attributes in the controller usually (receiving the values from a form). Here, I don't do more than calling the `Project`s `finish_date` setter.

Comment: Perhaps a mixture of @Joelio and my answer is the solution you're looking for? You use the callback to call the `finish_date` setter in `Project` and in that setter you perform the actions defined in @Joelio  `update_task_date`

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer @ErwinM. Did you end up using `update_attributes` or saving project explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

u can use **touch** option rather than a **after_save**.

If you set the :touch option to :true, then the updated_at or updated_on timestamp on the associated object will be set to the current time whenever this object is saved or destroyed. You can also specify a particular timestamp attribute to update.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, :touch => :project_end_date
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your issues are, but try it without callbacks first:

add a method to your task called update_task_date

```
def update_task_date(new_date)
  project.finish_date = new_date if self.project.finish_date < new_date
  project.save
  finish_date = new_date
  self.save
```

end

Comment: Actually, to stay in Rails' idea you had to overwrite `finish_date` setter in `task`. It's always better to overwrite a setter in Rails than to create a new method. You're supposed to call the setter anyway and Rails' "magic function" call the setters as well.

Comment: two things: (1) I always try to keep all the logic that changes a model, in the model itself. This implementation would spread the project logic to the Task model. (2) The task attributes are mostly updated through mass-assignment / update_attributes. How would that work then?

Comment: @ErwinM update_attributes is in fact calling the setter (you can see it by aliasing an attribute or just by defining a fake getter/setter and setting it accessible in the model.)

Answer (score 0):

What about an observer? Your model will be free from knowledge of other models, and you'll encapsulate that knowledge into a separate class.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html